# An op-amp connected to another op-amp, the one with ground and the other with virtual ground

Tags: operational-amplifier

When I have two op-amp circuits, the left one is connected to real ground and the output of this circuit is connected to the input of the right op-amp circuit which is connected to the virtual ground. How do I calculate Vo ?

[image: circuit]

Comment: What is the potential difference between the two grounds? You can easily calculate the output when you specify that information.

Comment: Is a part of a bigger circuit. But it confuses me that I have two grounds. The virtual ground circuit is shown here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346179/how-to-calculate-capacitor-and-resistors-on-virtual-ground-circuit?noredirect=1#comment822516_346179

Comment: One is "ground" and one is "virtual ground". Yet there's a 10 V difference between them. Okay.

Comment: So Vo = -(R4/R3)*V2 plus 10 Volt offset?

Comment: What is "real ground" and is there a connection.. somehow.. between the two?

Comment: @Trevor. Yes, see link at comment 2. Real ground = ground

Comment: Yes that link was my answer... but where is your "real ground" connected to. Your schematic does now show where that ground is connected, and calling it "real" does not mean anything.

Comment: @joe3489 Set up some proper equations rather than guessing. Also fix your naming, it's not good.

Comment: @ Harry Svensson. I know the equations for op-amps. But in this problem above with ground and virtual ground, I doubt that I know how to implement them correctly. That's why I ask here, in order to help me....

Comment: @joe3489 you need to draw us how the whole thing is wired up with the grounds. Just showing two points like that can mean different things.. Especially if the left op-amp is power by a different source or coming from a different board.

Comment: You also need to decide which ground U0, U1 and U2 are referenced from.

Answer (score 2):

OK Since you are not telling us where your grounds are connected I have to assume left ground is connected to the bottom of the 20V supply in your original post.

You have also not indicated which voltage U1, U2 and Uo are referenced to, so again I will make the assumption it is to the same side of the 20V supply.

As such you have the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8UU7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The formula for the second stage is

\$U_o = V_1 - (U_2- V_1).\frac{R_4}{R_3} \$

\$  = (\frac{R_4}{R_3}+1)V_1 - \frac{R_4}{R_3}.U_2\$

We know

\$U_2 = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}.U_1\$

So

\$U_o = (\frac{R_4}{R_3}+1)V_1 + \frac{R_4}{R_3}.\frac{R_2}{R_1}.U_1\$

Of course if the first of amp does not have a negative rail.. the above may be nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Ground in electronics only means 0V for some physical reference.

Virtual ground means a 0V differential reference such as in Op Amp inputs with the output in the linear range. In your case link Vcc/2 is defined as a virtual gnd to create single supply,  bipolar to single sided values.   If you can subtract then you properly figure this out. Include gain factors of OA.